# Field groups not showing when nested using field type HTML

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using Drupal 7.34, [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module, [Field groups 7.x-1.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group).

When building a form with nested field groups and using the fieldset field type, my form renders properly.

When I configure my form like this:

[image: HTML element nested field groups config]

It renders into this, showing nothing but the Title and Save button:

[image: Rendered form using nested fields]

There is nothing in the generated HTML as well, i.e. not hidden div's or something. The HTML markup just isn't there.

When I configure my form like this (changed nested fieldgroup element from HTML to Fieldset):

[image: Configuration using one single Fieldset]

It renders into this, showing all:

[image: Rendered result using one single Fieldset]

My goal is to have some nested HTML elements, which I am able to style in a theme. Am I doing something wrong with nested HTML elements?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [a bug found in a module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2311789) - these are not allowed here, you should post them in issue queue. There you would get pointed to existing bugreport and provided patch. Patch seems to be already included in dev version, too.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did not find this bug report (and believe me: I tried) so I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

the solution and patch can be found here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1503094#comment-11981615